# Cannot Access shared office 365 mailbox using exchange service in C#

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to read the shared mailbox of my organization which is managed through Microsoft365.
But I get error: **Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'**

Here is the code:

```
    `IConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
    .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
    .WithTenantId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
    .Build();

    string[] ewsScopes = new string[] {
        "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
    };

    AuthenticationResult authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
    string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

    if (accessToken != null)
    {

        var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
        ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(accessToken);
        ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "production@rvcapital.com");

        ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "production@abcd.com");

        var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(10));
    }`
```

I also tried adding this code:
`FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,"Shared@domain.com"); ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1000); service.FindItems(SharedMailbox,itemView);`

I am getting the error mentioned above when I call the FindFolders method in the last line. What steps to take ahead to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does your EWS code work against other mailboxes eg can you get the Inbox of the Mailbox you using in

ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "production@abcd.com");

A 403 can mean a number of things first is that EWS could be disabled on that mailbox or through a Application policy see https://practical365.com/new-application-access-policies-extend-support-for-more-scenarios/. You can use EWSEditor to test the availability of EWS against particular mailboxes https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor.

The other thing to do is check if your getting the correct permissions in access token with something like jwt.io you must have

[image]

which should look like

[image]

Comment: I cannot get 'full_access_as_app' from the administrator. What are the minimum permissions required to fulfil my task? @Glen Scales

Comment: Currently I have only one role: Mail.Read.

Comment: That won't work with EWS there is only one permission that works with EWS because its a legacy API. If you need to use that role then you will need to use the Graph API instead